# ceph-mon[1437]: warning: unable to create /var/run/ceph: (13) Permission denied

Tags: ceph

I followed the ceph document manual install，and I use tarballs. The installation process went smoothly, but when I run start service display warning

```
Started Ceph cluster monitor daemon.
ceph-mon[1437]: warning: unable to create /var/run/ceph: (13) Permission denied
ceph-mon[1437]: 2018-08-15 12:21:08.625 7f04fa393180 -1 asok(0x55dee6e4c240) AdminSocketConfigObs::init: failed:
```

so, I run

```
chmod 775 -R /var/run/
```

After, ceph-mon service is normal, but when the system is rebooted, the warning appears again.

I tried to change `/etc/ceph/ceph.conf`. I added:

```
[client]
admin socket = /tmp/ceph/$cluster-$name.asok
```

But it didn't work. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this question
total two methods

1、modify ceph-mon@.service file，ceph replace root

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/ceph-mon -f --cluster ${CLUSTER} --id %i --setuser root --setgroup root
```

or

2、modify ceph.conf file ,add

```
[mon]
run dir = XXXX (the path you want to use)
```

Answer (score 0):

please trie:

chown ceph:ceph /var/run/ceph

Comment: my ceph user is "root",so edit ceph-mon@.service file

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the directory /var/run/ceph exists. If not, create a directory and give permission to your ceph user

```
sudo mkdir /var/run/ceph
sudo chown ceph:ceph /var/run/ceph
```